# Modify the SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, community

Hi i need to modify the below SOQL query by adding the one more check can someone help me out
Query

```
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE HPR__c :number OR ADS__c = :number OR 
                   ASDR__c = :number OR ASDRT__c = :number
```

I need to add one more check dect=false then only quesry should return the result.

kindly help me out for this

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! That's a pretty basic task, and you'd probably be better served by going through some modules over on https://trailhead.salesforce.com to get a better understanding of what each part of a query does. The [Write SOQL queries](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_soql) unit of the Apex Basics & Database module, or the [SOQL for admins](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/soql-for-admins) module are likely to be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

So if i get your question correctly, by `"dect=false"` you mean a field on Account
Then the query should be like

```
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE yourCriteriaField = false AND (HPR__c = :number OR ADS__c = :number OR ASDR__c = :number OR ASDRT__c = :number)
```